# How can I transform my N little queries into one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that gives me the first available value for a given date and pair.

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 value
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    date >= 'myinputdate'
    AND key = 'myinpukey'
ORDER BY date
```

I have N pairs of key and dates, and I try to find out how not to query each pair one by one. The table is rather big, and N as well, so it's currently heavy and slow.

How can I query all the pairs in one query ?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @DavidG : what I expect is to get one result per key / date pair. The value for (date > 'date1' and key = 'key1'), the value for (date > 'date2' and key = 'key2'). In the case all pairs have a corresponding value, I'd like to get N results out of N pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use `APPLY` like a "function" created on the fly with one or many columns from another set:

```
DECLARE @inputs TABLE (
    myinputdate DATE,
    myinputkey INT)

INSERT INTO @inputs(
    myinputdate,
    myinputkey)
VALUES
    ('2019-06-05', 1),
    ('2019-06-01', 2)

SELECT
    I.myinputdate,
    I.myinputkey,
    R.value
FROM
    @inputs AS I
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            T.value
        FROM
            my_table AS T
        WHERE
            T.date >= I.myinputdate AND
            T.key = I.myinputkey
        ORDER BY
            T.date ) AS R
```

You can use `OUTER APPLY` if you want `NULL` result values to be shown also. This supports fetching multiple columns and using `ORDER BY` with `TOP` to control amount of rows.

Comment: Your inputs needs to be kept on a table as they are multiple rows. Can either be a variable table (starts with @), temporary table (starts with #) or physical one (persistent). I've included an example with a variable table.

Comment: Grand, thank you man. As I understand it, it will run the query for each pair. Do you think it will imply a performance gain compared to multiple queries ?

Comment: Yes, relational databases are optimized to work in sets. Avoid 1 by 1 queries or operations whenever possible.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is without variables. You control your **N** by setting the right value to the `row_num` predicate.

There are plenty of ways how to do you what you want and it all depends on your specific needs. As it answered already, that you can use temp/variable table to store these conditions and then join it on the same conditions you use predicates. You can also create user defined data type and use it as param to the function/procedure. You might use `CROSS APPLY` + `VALUES` clause to get that list and then join it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp ( d DATE, k VARCHAR(100) );
GO

INSERT  INTO #temp
VALUES  ( '20180101', 'a' ),
        ( '20180102', 'b' ),
        ( '20180103', 'c' ),
        ( '20180104', 'd' ),
        ( '20190101', 'a' ),
        ( '20190102', 'b' ),
        ( '20180402', 'c' ),
        ( '20190103', 'c' ),
        ( '20190104', 'd' );

SELECT  a.d ,
        a.k
FROM    ( SELECT    d ,
                    k ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY k ORDER BY d DESC ) row_num
          FROM      #temp
          WHERE     (d >= '20180401'
                    AND k = 'a')
                    OR (d > '20180401'
                    AND k = 'b')
                    OR (d > '20180401'
                    AND k = 'c')
        ) a
WHERE   a.row_num <= 1;

-- VALUES way
SELECT  a.d ,
        a.k
FROM    ( SELECT    t.d ,
                    t.k ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.k ORDER BY t.d DESC ) row_num
          FROM      #temp t
          CROSS APPLY (VALUES('20180401','a'), ('20180401', 'b'), ('20180401', 'c')) f(d,k)
          WHERE t.d >= f.d AND f.k = t.k

        ) a
WHERE   a.row_num <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the keys are using the same date, then use window functions:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY date) as seqnum
      FROM my_table t
      WHERE date >= @input_date AND
            key IN ( . . . )
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: So you mean the date is the same in all pairs? Then, it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT key, date,value
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key,date ORDER BY date) as rownum,key,date,value
          FROM my_table
WHERE
    date >= 'myinputdate'


         ) as d
    WHERE d.rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Does it only work for a unique date across all the pairs ?

Comment: The partition is on key,date  field and order by date field...so the outer query filter the rownum=1 for each key,date pair

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand what does your query. Does it gives the result for any key/date pair that exist in the table ?